# Web design standards

Tags: php, design, seo

While designing web pages using php, are there standards that should be followed? For example suppose there are two pages. First page looks like this:

```
<body>
<div>
<?php include 'page2.php';?>
```

`page2.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php print 'some text';?>
</div>
</body>
```

Is such designing a standard practice? Does it affect search engine results?

Answer (score 3):

You generate legal HTML that way, but I wouldn't recommend it. Putting a closing tag in a different file than the opening tag makes for poor readability and error prone design. As opposed to many other dubious designs I don't see any upside of this either, you will not be able to implement some smart trick because of this practice.

Comment: I believe that's just an example, generally you would use the include to pull content and then wrap it in tags.

Comment: Yes, something like `<body><? include ?></body>` is perfectly legit. My point is just that you should match tags within the same file, you shouldn't have `<body>` and `</body>` in two different files.

Comment: I totally agree with eBusiness. For a maintenance perspective, this will cost you a handful of hair.

Comment: Actually I often have the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags in separate views. A head view and a footer / tail view.

Comment: Well, I guess that works OK, as long as it is part of a well defined structure it should be manageable.

Comment: Whilst agreeing with @eBusiness and others, it should be observed that WordPress et al tend to split tags in their various template files...

Answer (score 1):

What matters is the response, or what gets sent to the browser / crawler. How that is done server side doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks josh. but is such designing followed in standard websites?

Comment: @Sanket: Yes, it's completely standard. Though that exact implementation might be a bit simple.

Answer (score 1):

**What you have there is idiomatic HTML generation**

No problem with that - if you're happy to maintain it. As others have said, it is the final response that is important.

**How can you check your response?**

Use the [Web Developer toolbar for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/?id=60), which will manage access to these validation sites from W3C:

1. [XHTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/)
2. [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Ideally, you should target XHTML Strict but your requirements may vary.

**And the search engine?**

It won't see how you generate the response, it will only see the response. Search engines on the whole prefer to see well-formed, standards compliant XHTML simply because it's easier for them to parse. However, check out the [Google web master notes](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291) for what they look for in order to promote your site to the top of the search results. (Hint: Google wants timely, relevant content that is considered to be the definitive resource as a result of others approving it).